# Why doesn't JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisPool() pass the dbIndex?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis

The JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet method ultimately creates a new JedisPool object but doesn't pass the dbIndex.

Because it's ommitted, the database for that pool reverts to Protocol.DEFAULT_DATABASE, which if you've configured the JedisConnectionFactory database property otherwise, is wrong.

Since you can define the database property of the JedisConnectionFactory, why is this value not passed through to the JedisPool constructor?

JedisPool has other constructors that will allow dbIndex to passed so is there a reason for this behaviour?

I'm currently using spring-data-redis version 1.6.2 but this doesn't appear to have changed int the latest version on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.java.

Comment: the `JedisConnectionFactory` creates a new `JedisConnection` on calling `getConnection()` which calls `select` with the given `dbindex` (see: [JedisConnection.java#L197](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnection.java#L197)). Please feel free to open an issue in JIRA providing insight on what exactly is not working for you.